# Crash in AOSP when calling Activity.startActivities(Intent [] intents) on application start

Tags: android, android-activity, android-task

I struggle resolving a crash which either comes from my own bad implementation due to missing knowledge or from AOSP code (less likely I think...).
It seems to only occurs on Android 13 and I got it mainly on Samsung devices (Galaxy S23+/S22+/S22 Ultra/S21 FE 5G) I don't own (happened also 1 time on OPPO Reno5, Xiaomi 12 & Xiaomi 11T).
Here is the stacktrace:

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.android.server.wm.ActivityRecord com.android.server.wm.WindowContainer.getActivity(java.util.function.Predicate)' on a null object reference
android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull (Parcel.java:3029)
android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:3007)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2990)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2932)
android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivities (IActivityTaskManager.java:2816)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivitiesAsUser (Instrumentation.java:1876)
android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivities (Instrumentation.java:1823)
android.app.Activity.startActivities (Activity.java:6096)
android.app.Activity.startActivities (Activity.java:6069)
.SplashActivity.startMain (SplashActivity.java:149)
```

I already searched in AOSP code to understand how the `WindowContainer` could be `null` in `IActivityTaskManager.startActivities` which implementation seems to be [`ActivityTaskManagerService.startActivities`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/ActivityTaskManagerService.java;l=1214?q=ActivityTaskManagerService.startactivities&sq=) but it's hard to navigate deep into the AOSP code... Also I tried to search for [`WindowContainer.getActivity`](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/main/+/main:frameworks/base/services/core/java/com/android/server/wm/WindowContainer.java;l=1821?q=windowcontainer.getActivity&sq=) usage but cross-references does not seem to work for this file... I also cloned the repository through the `repo` cmd as per the doc but I did not find the files... So I'm stuck :/

I have implemented a `SplashActivity` handling main launcher intent and any background notification and deep link clicks launching the correct activity or stack.
I got only the crash when I need to launch the `list -> details` stack.

Here is its minimal comprehensive code:

```
public final class SplashActivity {
    private boolean resumed;

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        fetchAsyncData(SplashActivity::onDataFetched())
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostResume() {
        super.onPostResume();

        resumed = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        resumed = false;
    }

    public void onDataFetched() {
        String res1, res2;
        // some code to parse either a deep link or background notification, ending in populated res1 & res2 or not
        // do not start any activity if not resumed (user goes back to home/other app/kills the app)
        if (resumed) {
            if (res1 != null && res2 != null) {
                Intent intent = getIntent();
                Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

                Intent listIntent = new Intent(this, ListActivity.class);
                // forward extras/flags to new root intent
                listIntent.putExtras(extras != null ? extras : new Bundle());
                listIntent.addFlags(intent.getFlags());

                Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(this, DetailsActivity.class);
                detailsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                detailsIntent.putExtra("res1", res1);
                detailsIntent.putExtra("res2", res2);

                startActivities(new Intent[]{listIntent, detailsIntent});
                finish();
            }
            else {
                // start other activities
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And here is how `SplashActivity`, `ListActivity` and `DetailsActivity` are declared in the `AndroidManifest.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <application>
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleInstance"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true" tools:targetApi="m">
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                <data
                    android:scheme="https"
                    android:host="example.com"
                    android:pathPattern="/res1/.*/res2/.*" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".ListActivity"
            android:exported="true"
            android:launchMode="singleTop" />
        <activity
            android:name=".DetailsActivity"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:exported="true"
            android:parentActivityName=".ListActivity">
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value=".ListActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: Any luck in resolving this issue? Even we are facing this issue for Android 13 devices intermittently

Comment: We are facing this issue on Samsung Galaxy A52 (SM-A525M). Did you solve or open a bug to the AOSP?

Comment: Same here, on devices Galaxy S21 Ultra 5G, Galaxy F23 5G, Galaxy A51 5G.
All Android 13. No fix yet...

Comment: @MarcoRighini I think I've found a fix on my side (see answer below).
I did not filed a bug to AOSP yet, thinking that's more a misunderstanding on my side, more since I've possibly fixed it, I'm waiting a deployment in production to be sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated the above code to use `TaskStackBuilder` instead as it seems I've implemented it that way before but changed it, I don't know why...
I'll let you know if this fixed the crash (again?), supposing that `startActivities` method is sort of deprecated :/

```
public void onDataFetched() {
    String res1, res2;
    
    // some code to parse either a deep link or background notification, 
    // ending in populated res1 & res2 or not
    
    // do not start any activity if not resumed
    // (user goes back to home/other app/kills the app)
    if (resumed) {
        if (res1 != null && res2 != null) {
            Intent intent = getIntent();
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();

            Intent detailsIntent = new Intent(context, DetailsActivity.class);
            detailsIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP 
                                   | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("res1", res1);
            detailsIntent.putExtra("res2", res2);

            TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(context);
            stackBuilder.addNextIntentWithParentStack(detailsIntent);
            
            // forward extras/flags to list intent 
            // automatically added as new root because
            // declared as parent activity of DetailsActivity in AndroidManifest.xml
            Intent listIntent = stackBuilder.editIntentAt(0);
            if (listIntent != null)
            {
                listIntent.putExtras(extras != null ? extras : new Bundle());
                listIntent.addFlags(intent.getFlags());
            }

            stackBuilder.startActivities();
            finish();
        }
        else {
            // start other activities
        }
    }
}
```